# UPDATE mariaDB Query issues

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb

got a permanent 1064 error with this query on mariaDB:

```
UPDATE field_news
SET friendly_url = REPLACE (friendly_url, ' ', '-')
WHERE id_news = $idNews;
```

The $idNews variable is well-set.
I broke my brains trying to find why mariaDB rejects the query.
If someone can bring me some light on this.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be doing this update from you PHP code.  You *could* make the quick fix of putting single quotes around `$idNews`.  But instead, you should ideally be using a prepared statement here:

```
UPDATE field_news
SET friendly_url = REPLACE (friendly_url, ' ', '-')
WHERE id_news = ?;
```

To the `?` placeholder, you would bind the actual PHP variable `$idNews`.  Your PHP code might then look something like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE field_news
        SET friendly_url = REPLACE (friendly_url, ' ', '-')
        WHERE id_news = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $idNews);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Note one of the advantages of prepared statements is that they handle worrying about how to bind variables to your query.